# Dashboard.js Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to create Dashboard Panel from BIM 360 Construction cloud Revit files
Please guide me how to change the Properties into Category?, also how to create different type of charts other then “Bar” & “Pie chart”

Example : Rooms, Room Numbers and information within the Rooms etc,

Presently I am following .NET Core – Visual Studio 2019 Community version, and created up to Viewer as per training classes

See below the extract from https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/dashboard,
Presently it is showing “Materials” in “Barchart & “Piechart”

[image]

Regards
Prakash Pisipati

Answer (score 0):

We have expanded the use of this tutorial to the approach you are looking for. Basically in the BIM 360 Reports app we add a dropdown menu that contains all the different properties that are available per model loaded. In the tutorial we use 'Material' since most AEC and MFG models contain this property. You can test a quick load of 'Category' in either the BarChart or PieChart by simply doing a swap, take into consideration that the model loading needs to have this property.

Here you can find the code to avoid the hardcoding of the properties and to load the graphs with the selected one you prefer.

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360reports/blob/staging/public/js/Dashboard/DashboardPanel.js#L59

Now, in regard the use of different graphs, yes you can use whatever you desire, we are using Chart.js and they have many options available for you to look into. You can use the same structure of data we have given to the Bar and Pie Charts and one quick test can be swap everything that has 'doughnut' to 'polarArea'

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/polar-area.html

Comment: Thanks, I have updated "Dashboardpanel.js"still I am seeing materials in the dashboard panel, also it keep changing while hovering above that any reason why?,                         
How to control as a static selection? say example Floor level in the Bar chart and Room department in the Pie chart. also how to apply colors for different departments? Presently I am using "View Hub Models"